# How to make an iterator be "automatically dereferenced"?

Tags: c++, c++11, iterator

Suppose I have something like this:

```
class Collection
{
private:
    typedef std::vector< std::shared_ptr<Something> >::iterator Iterator;
    std::vector< std::shared_ptr<Something> > data_;

public:
    Iterator begin() {return data_.begin()}
    Iterator end()  {return data_.end()}
}
```

When I use a `Collection::Iterator` instance I need to dereference it once, to get the `std::shared_ptr<Something>` object and once again to get `Something` object.

But if I want to make the `std::shared_ptr<Something>` just an implementation detail, it is reasonable that after one dereferencing, I should get a `Something` object.

That is:

```
Collection collection;
Collection::Iterator it = collection.begin();
Something firstMember = *it;  // instead of the current **it;
```

My question is, do I need to make the Iterator as a nested class of `Collection` from scratch and implement all the functions required for a random access iterator from here http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/std/iterator/ or is there some well known approach? Possibly C++11?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It sounds like what you're implementing exists and is called [`boost::ptr_vector`](http://www.boost.org/libs/ptr_container/).  Boost also provides [a library](http://www.boost.org/libs/iterator/) for implementing iterators with less pain.  It sounds like what you're looking for is [`boost::indirect_iterator`](http://www.boost.org/libs/iterator/doc/indirect_iterator.html)

Comment: The boost::indirect_iterator is EXACTLY what I am looking for! Thank you!